# Best way to get up-to-date kernel with Kubuntu

Tags: kernel, updates, kubuntu, update-alternatives

I installed Kubuntu 16.04 on a brand new Dell Laptop. I got kernel errors related to the graphics drivers and found out that the problem can be solved with a kernel >= 4.6.

So the question now is:
What is the best (i.e. less stressful, more stable and less risky) way to get such a new kernel? Should I switch to the non-LTS Kubuntu 16.10 (with kernel 4.8) or is it better to stick with the LTS 16.04 and install a selected kernel like described in http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/install-linux-kernel-4-7-ubuntu-16-04/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and the only supported way is to install the officially supported 4.8 kernel by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

It will get updates from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Great, thanks! Out of curiosity: The way described in the above link wouldn't work?

Comment: That was published before the official way appeared. It will install an unsupported kernel.